# How to make an Account inactive on R3 Corda

Tags: corda

We need to make an Account inactive when we finish a process and search for active and inactive accounts for history.

Is there an attribute to make the Account inactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently that is not possible because `AccountInfo` has [only one command](https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/900fe9c2ebf4ad8ecda1f494c03f747ef1579746/contracts/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/accounts/contracts/commands/AccountInfoCommands.kt#L9) (i.e. `Create`).

Btw, there would be many complications of deactivating an account:

- What happens to the states where that account is a participant? It should be replaced with a different account before deactivation; otherwise after deactivating it, you won't be able to acquire its signature if needed, so those states become "unusable".
- Also, the related private/public keys would have to be retired. Currently the node stores a mapping between the `UUID` of `AccountInfo` and all related keys. There should be some mechanism to remove those keys from the node. It shouldn't be able to use them for signing after deactivating the account, because they represent that account.